# Shortest way from a number to another in a clamped range

Tags: c#, floating-point, range

I have a `float`, and it's clamped between two other `floats`, forming a range of possible values for it. In my setup, if the value goes over either endpoint of the range, it will flow over to the other side. That is, if the value is clamped between 0 and 10 and the value itself is 9, adding 2 to it makes it flow to 0 (`9 -> 10 -> 0`)

I need to calculate the shortest "path" between two values in the range, so if I wanted to know the shortest way from 2 to 9, it'd be `2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 10 -> 9`, which means I would have to subtract 4 from it.

I've been trying to figure out a solution but I just can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Actually, it is int, not a float, isn't it?

Comment: @tsdaemon The value can be of any type. I just used integers in the examples.

Comment: Ok but your numbers is integral?

Comment: I mean, without a fractional parts? Because it doesn't make sense, there are infinite count of fractional numbers between two fractional numbers.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the fractions aren't an issue. If I want 2f to be 3f,  I'd add 1f to it. If I want 2f to be 3.5f, I'd add 1.5f to it. The values can be fractions, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding that if the range is between 0 and 10 then 2 + 9 is 0, I would expect 2 + 9 to be 1. What would you say is the outcome of 1.5 + 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your example, it takes 1 to go from upper range value to lower when calculate overflow. So I used it as constant.

```cs
float a,b, bound1, bound2; // input data
var path1 = b - a; // straight way
var absPath1 = Math.Abs(path1);
var range = bound2 - bound1;
var path2 = range - absPath1 + 1;
if(b > a) path2 = -path2;
var absPath2 = Math.Abs(path2);
var shortestPath = absPath1 > absPath2 ? path1 : path2;
```

Comment: This works fine otherwise but I want the result to be what I'd have to add to `a` for it to be `b`. Right now, if `a` is, say, 7 and `b` is 5, this returns 2 but it should return -2.

Comment: try new implementation